# Background music on rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, background-music

I try to add background sound in a rails app. The code is like this:

```
embed src="followme.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true"
```

but where should I put the sound? In the assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easy Answer

Put the file in the `public/` directory.  Example: `public/my_audio_file.mp3`

### Better, Cleaner Answer

Put all of your audio files in a single folder like: `public/audio/my_audio_file.mp3`.  Then do something like:

```
embed src="audio/my_audio_file.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties tab at the top ... select your project properties and then go to References. Make a new reference folder if one does not exist, and Add Reference. Now select the path wherever you have created the object audio file from its properties. Simple eh :)

Comment: I won't -1 as the answer is right. Text speak is really unnecessary, 'your' and 'then' are not long words and can be easier understood by translators and non native speakers.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds silly but the folder "references" where you tell me to create and put the sound will be in the 'app' folder?

Comment: It will be a really different folder. You don.t need to create one . It will be automatically created. Go to the REFERENCES Tab, & it will automatically detect abscence of such a folder first, it will ask you to create one to which you will agree. There and then ADD REFERENCE from the tab above and select audio file from your source.

Comment: @Oshawott I will take care of this in future bro